# Android LVL Custom License Period

Tags: android, android-lvl

I am working on app that will be used 30-40 days off-line(no Internet connection), so I need LVL to work offline for that period with ManagedPolicy. 
The check is done at the Start - and if it cannot to connect to the server to use the saved policy for the next 30-40 days.
I am looking for some example or advice to implement that kind of custom policy.

Comment: So, Ken, why are you shouting in your comment?

Comment: Thanks Ken for the fix..just was sleeping, didn't see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching few hours with google, I found only single example

https://gist.github.com/Ricket/1163927 
"Modified ServerManagedPolicy which only requires licensing to be verified every 7 days or 10 tries. (from the Android licensing library)"

It is start point for further implementation and so long the best example that exist.

If someone has more info, please share it - it will be very helpfull.

Comment: OK, using "Modified ServerManagedPolicy" example I did my own custom policy. The example was life saver :)))

Comment: how do You implement this new policy? changing the .class in the google vending jar file?

Comment: Nope, changing the ServerManagedPolicy.java file. Check the standard ServerManagedPolicy.java and the one from the link https://gist.github.com/Ricket/1163927 
But be careful , I had some problems with it - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15385019/android-pending-intent-alarm-same-code-six6-apps/15403695#15403695