# Android pending Intent - Alarm - same code six(6) apps

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, alarm, android-pendingintent

I found something strange yesterday. While testing app with localization versions(different apps-dif. packages, the same code) I found one interesting bug -  the app sets alarm with the AlarmManager and pending Intent - when the broadcast is fired , only one app gets activated and executes the pending intent and all others apps(only different language) are not reacting at all. Is this android bug?? I'm expecting that the set Alarm will trigger every one app that has it's own set Alarm but Android is starting or the last active app is triggered by the broadcast or receive broadcast?  how is the pending Intent associated with the Broadcast from the System? How the System knows which app is expecting Broadcast and which one for this .apk?
It may seems strange or hard to understand but Im confused too..

```
public class AlarmSetter  {

    public void SetAlarma(Context context){

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 57);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23); 
    calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 0);

     Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmKicked.class);
     PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 1333333, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
     AlarmManager am =(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
     am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,
             pendingIntent);       
    }

}
```

Comment: I had 6 language versions Installed on that system..

Comment: Broadcast is sent through the system - to all.. OK I get that.. but why by only one from the 6 was executed "onReceive" and by the other 5 didn't?

Comment: a little bit off-topic: why you have 6 installations for 6 languages? You may want to Check http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html#using-framework
Using this, you wont have your current problem at all.

Comment: as stand alone app it is just fine, my question is what happens when we have the same code.. some collision or what??? I will check this one more time later today

Comment: ok, thats an argument. just thought it could be a solution. ;) Does the broadcast ever reach the other languages (write something to log inside onReceive)?

Comment: the app has 6 language versions -why they are separated?Very Simply - I will get more data and info for every one language, single language is better performance - no need to check for the strings if they exist - just uses the default.  I think that it is better for better control and I get very good look at the data - which language gets downloaded and how many times.. If someone needs to have second language - he must to pay for it.. the translation costs money too..

Comment: I will post later about what I found.. now I must to do something else before to go back to the testing.

Comment: Post the code you use to schedule the alarm

Comment: @David the code is posted.
I think that two thing can be causing the problem:
- .FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT 
- and the most important "context, 1333333" the id 1333333.. I don't know how android manages the pending intents but if it has the same id maybe android is executing only ones the intent and the others are just skipped... using the same code in 6 apps can have Consequences. I will do some testing to confirm that

Comment: If you have different apps with different packages, then there **shouldn't** be a conflict with the `PendingIntent`. However...there may be a bug in Android related to this. What you could try is to make sure the `PendingIntent`s are different by adding a unique **action** to the `Intent` you pass to `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()`. For example, you could do something like `intent.setAction(getPackageName() + ".ALARM")`

Comment: 03-15 23:59:57.899: I/ActivityManager(59): Start proc packetXit:remote for broadcast packetXit/.AlarmKicked: pid=418 uid=10044 gids={1015}

03-15 23:59:58.510: I/ActivityManager(59): No longer want android.process.acore (pid 172): hidden #16


Don't get it, nothing works... just starts single one from 6 - Alarmkicked is executed.. the other 5 are sleeping..

Comment: Finally I Found the BUG!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, waiting for confirmation about the bug

OK, finally!!!!

It is  a LVL BUG:
So , the app is bg.google.myapppackage.apk .. nothing wrong.. uses LVL license - ServerManagedPolicy - customized - bcs google says the developers are using the example..

In the ServerManagedPolicy.java we have " private static final String DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES = "0";"  I just did " private static final String DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES = "10";"
That means 10 times to start before lockdown.. nothing new , the user can to start the app before the 10 checks are gone.. nice, isn't it?

BUT! the problem is in the LVL , every start is registered by the system in very strange way.. how? simply:
every start adds number to the package , like this

03-17 00:25:45.318: I/PackageManager(59): /data/app/bg.google.myapppackage-1.apk changed; unpacking

03-17 00:25:45.318: I/PackageManager(59): /data/app/bg.google.myapppackage-2.apk changed; unpacking

03-17 00:25:45.318: I/PackageManager(59): /data/app/bg.google.myapppackage-3.apk changed; unpacking

those are the times that the app was started... ok still nothing wrong... Nope!THIS IS WRONG! If you start the activity from package bg.google.myapppackage-1.apk and this package sets Alarm with the AlarmManager and you close the app , later the Alarm will be fired but the receiver will no any more exist.. bcs if the users close the app and start it again then we have bg.google.myapppackage-2.apk and the second package sets Alarm two, but when it is beeing closed the package doesn't exist any more... The system fires Broadcast but there is no Receiver and the app is not reacting at all. this was the problem in my case.. testing the app and never got Broadcast or only  the active app registered the brodcast and the others didn't..

So if you have app that is doing some update that is triggered by the AlarmManager, you must  to set the " private static final String DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES = "0";" to 0 otherwise in the retries period your app will show malfunction, or missing functionality // I think that Google must to fix that with changing the name of the package and someone must to post BUG Ticket.. This thing costed me almost 3 days(days I study IT, and nights I work at home.. so sleeping is something that I miss, and losing time like this is not wanted..)

03-14 18:22:51.860: D/PackageManager(199): New package installed in /data/app/bg.google.myapppackage-1.apk

03-17 00:25:45.348: D/installd(35): DexInv: --- BEGIN '/data/app/bg.google.myapppackage-1.apk' ---

03-17 00:25:47.599: D/installd(35): DexInv: --- END '/data/app/bg.google.myapppackage-1.apk' (success) ---

03-17 00:25:47.748: I/installd(35): move /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@bg.google.myapppackage-1.apk@classes.dex -> /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@bg.google.myapppackage-1.apk@classes.dex

Comment: So I hope that this will be helpfull for others.

Comment: fixed issue with the LVL License - ServerManagedPolicy